# How to Map new route to specific old route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, php-7

I have following route group for admin panel

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function (){
.
.
.}
```

I want to wrap this route to a new route e.g `asda12asda`

so that old behavior  :

```
/admin/users
```

is changed to :

```
/asda12asda/users
```

not allowing old route. I don't want to change it internally from the system and want to find some efficient Laravel way to achieve it.

Comment: Do you want to redirect all the routes within admin prefix to a new url OR any specific route within the group?

Comment: I don't want to change the old routes which are being used within the code e.g admin/users , admin/item

and on the other hand , I want to change the login , and avoid admin/login and make it asda12asda/login .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the old route to a new route

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function (){    
    Route::any('login', function () {
        // Redirect to new route
        redirect()->route('new route');
    });
});
```

by creating a new route and mapping it accordingly

```
Route::prefix('asda12asda')->group(function () {
    Route::any('login', function () {
        // Do whatever you were about to do
    })->name('new route');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using Laravel 5.4 then you can add a new route file. Assume your route name is
adsp.php then add it to RouteServiceProvider.php like this.

protected function mapApiRoutes()
  {
    Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'web',
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/adsp.php.php');
    });
}
```